# android-how to animate repeating with offset that works only at the start

Tags: android

I have an array of views and i'm trying to animate all of them using the same animation but with different delays at the beginning:

```
View[] arr;
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{
    Animation anim=new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0,-200);
    anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    anim.setDuration(300);
    anim.setRepeatMode(2);
    anim.setStartTime(startTime+i*1000);
    arr[i].startAnimation(anim);
}
```

I have also tried to use `setStartOffSet(i*100)` but it happend every time (at every repeate they had the delay) and not just at the start of the animation so they got out of sync.

I would like to imply a delay only once on start.

Comment: Have you tried something like `arr[i].animate().translationY(-200f).setDuration(300).setStartDelay(startTime+i*1000).start()` ?

Comment: I tried, now instead of having bugs it's not working at all.

Answer (score 0):

DELAYS ARE BAD

If You Insert your Views into a ListView, All you'd need would be this:

```js
...

ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(...);

ArrayAdapter mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter < Item > (getContext(), R.layout.ITEM_LAYOUT, Your_itemArray) {
  @NonNull
  @Override
  public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    View myView;
    ...

    if (convertView == null) {
      LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
      myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ITEM_LAYOUT, parent, false);
      ...

    } else {
      myView = convertView;
    }


    // -----YOUR ANIMATION TIME--------------------------------------
    ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myView, View.TRANSLATION_X, You_Desired_Distance, 0);
    anim.setInterpolator(WHATEVER_INTERPOLATION_YOU_WANT);
    anim.setDuration(300).start();
    //---------------------------------------------------------------


    return myView;
  }
}


list.setAdapter(mAdapter);

...
```

This will Animate the Views One After the Other, just the way You want

However, If You are Using RecyclerView you can Use ViewHolder to do this.

And If you are not Using any kind of List at all, Well that wouldn't be productive and You Have to Use Lots of `DELAYS` and DELAYS ARE BAD

Try to Avoid Delay and Use Lists Instead

Also, ObjectAnimators are so powerful, So Study them carefully to achieve the best results in animation

Comment: thanks but I am using views that are not in the same listView

Comment: Thats unfortunate, But you have put your animation inside a for loop, thats a lot of views you want to Animate. Please consider ListView or recyclerview, I know you think you can make it work with delay, but I have done this before and its gonna work bad this way. I will give you a code for ListView implementation as well if you want. Have a good day